# Correct Policy to force using of MFA with CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, multi-factor-authentication

I have problem understanding AWS policies and MFA with CLI.
I'm trying to prevent running my Powershell script without correct MFA Token.
In My   script process and CLI commands goes in this order:

1. Ask profile, MFA devices serial and MFA Token.
2. sts Assume-role
3. api gateway import-rest-api

Seems that I can't get policy right with import-rest-api command. It either allows running import command always (with or without correct MFA) Or some other policy I have tried doesn't allow that CLI command even with correct MFA.
How policy should be done to allow import-rest-api command only with MFA?
Basically in my script every other CLI command should require MFA beside this aws apigateway import-rest-api.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            },
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAssumeRoleWithMFA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "sts:AssumeRole"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:iam::681278469643:user/newUserMumbai:role/TestiRooli1"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowImportAPIWithMFA",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "apigateway:POST",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "Bool": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            }
        },
```

Comment: Can you provide some more detail on what you are trying to acomplish?  Is this permission policy for whatever principal assumes the Role, or is it for the Role?  Do you use the Role's credentials to call `apigateway:ImportRestAPI` or your initial principal's?  If the initial principal's, then what is the reason for assuming a Role?  If the Role's, then do you intend that MFA be required to assume the Role, or for the Role to call `apigateway:ImportRestAPI`?

Comment: I try accomplish that to run those CLI scripts you have to have IAM User with MFA and that user uses a role (for example "DevRole") and Role has policy named like "RequireMFA".  
Let me know if there is a better way to force use of MFA with CLI scripts.

Comment: Ok, so you start with IAM User credentials, use those to assume a Role, and the permission policy that you quote is attached to the Role.  What permissions does the User have?  Are you using the User's permissions to call `apigateway:ImportRestAPI`, or the Role's?

Comment: This new user has not been given any special permissions. Only that same "RequireMFA" policy which role has have been added to user directly also.
in .Aws folder credentials file I have profile with that  new users access keys. When I start to run script I use that profile and also new users MFA. I have added that same "requireMFA" policy also for my own user.